# Chrome view-source versus POST

Tags: rest, google-chrome

When you ask Chrome to View/Source, it resubmits your URL as a GET, even if it got there in the first place as a post. Is there some way around this for those of us debugging JAX-RS services invoked from forms that can't work with GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two workarounds from this page:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1082a452e274f6db&hl=en

1. Find a working View Source plugin such as "View Source With": http://members.iinet.net.au/~bertdb/ryan/ViewSourceWith/help.html
2. Workaround:

   - Open developer tools.
   - Turn on resource tracking
   - LEAVE THE TOOLS OPEN. Click on Elements.
   - Top half should be page. Bottom half should be source code.
   - Click the Submit button in the top half. Your source code should now update to the proper POSTed source.

Comment: Elements actually shows the current state of the page. The Resources tab shows you the unparsed, unmodified source code.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + SHIFT + I